# Short read or OOM loading DB. Unrecoverable error, aborting now

Tags: linux, redis, centos

After restating my server I am not able to start the redis. From the log I found this message `"Short read or OOM loading DB. Unrecoverable error, aborting now."`. I am new to redis and don't know what to do to resolve the issue. Also I am not able to find any solid solution for this. Please help

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Warning: This will permanently delete your database.
Use only if you don't care about the data stored or if you have a backup.**

I solved the problem like this:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb
rm -rf /var/run/redis.pid
service redis-server start
```

Then it is OK.

Comment: stopping the service and deleting `/var/lib/redis/dump.rdb` then restarting the service actually helped me. +1 thanks!

Comment: For me, the dump.rdb was in a different location but removing the file fixed it!

Comment: works great, but just rememmber to change the last line to service redis-server start

Comment: This solution is deleting the database without a warning even...be careful if you actually care about the data.

Answer (score 7):

Cause of this error [might be similar to a known one](http://code.google.com/p/redis/issues/detail?id=303).

Your disk is full so when redis tries to create a db file it fails because there is no space left on the disk and it creates zero sized db file. Starting redis fails because of zero sized db file, in CentOS db file path is like this

```
/var/lib/redis/dump.rdb
```

In newer versions of redis this bug is fixed, if you use older version of redis simply removing dump.rdb will work for you. But do this if `dump.rdb` file size is zero, otherwise do not because you might lose data.

Comment: How much disk does Redis require?

Comment: Redis requirement depends on your usage I guess. But for this problem it's not about how much Redis requires, the problem is disc does not have any free space so Redis cannot create the dump file.

Comment: I solved my problem, thank you! The problem was disk space all the time, but even uninstalling and installing redis again (after freeing more disk space), it didn't work. I think it didn't work because I was using Redis that comes in the Gitlab bundle. The only thing that solved the problem was to reinstall Ubuntu. No problems ocurred in this clean install.